# Cannot get Automapper to ignore a property

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following set up for automapper;

```
cfg.CreateMap<NewBuildBlockViewModel, NewBuildBlock>();
cfg.CreateMap<NewBuildBlockAreaViewModel, NewBuildBlockArea>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore()).ForMember(x => x.Created, opt => opt.Ignore())
                    .ForMember(x => x.LastModifiedBy, opt => opt.Ignore()).ForMember(x => x.LastModified, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

So for the second mapping I want to ignore the audit fields.
The classes are as follows

```
public class NewBuildBlockViewModel
{
    public NewBuildBlockViewModel()
    {
        NewBuildBlockArea = new List<NewBuildBlockAreaViewModel>();
    }

    public int NewBuildBlockId { get; set; }
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public IList<NewBuildBlockAreaViewModel> NewBuildBlockArea { get; set; }

}

public class NewBuildBlockAreaViewModel
{
    public int NewBuildBlockAreaId { get; set; }
    public int NewBuildBlockId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsPlot { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeletable { get; set; }
}

public class NewBuildBlock : IAuditCreated, IAuditLastModified
{
    [Key] public int NewBuildBlockId { get; set; }

    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public List<NewBuildBlockArea> NewBuildBlockArea { get; set; }
}

public class NewBuildBlockArea : IAuditCreated, IAuditLastModified
{
    [Key] public int NewBuildBlockAreaId { get; set; }
    public int NewBuildBlockId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsPlot { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public NewBuildBlock NewBuildBlock { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

So as you can see I am mapping a class with a nested list
During the mapping I would like the audit fields to be ignored, but for the lists I am finding that they are being set to their default values instead, so Created show the minimum date 01/01/0001 and CreatedBy is set to null.
What is wrong with this code? I am using version 6.1.1.

```
var originalNewBuild = this.SirUoW.NewBuildBlock.GetItem(                    
    x => x.BlockUPRN == blockUPRN && x.ContractId == contractId, x => 
    x.NewBuildBlockArea);

var newNewBuild = Mapper.Map(newBuildBlockViewModel, originalNewBuild);
```

Comment: If `Created` is marked as ignored in the mapper config then Automapper should effectively ignore it not assigning anything to them and the CLR will just initialize them with their default values. Since DateTime is a struct, it needs to have some value so it will be initialized as `default(DateTime)` which is the minimum possible DateTime. As `CreatedBy` I'm not sure what's happening, `string` is a reference type so its default value should be `null`, are you sure `CreatedBy` is set to empty and not `null`?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: I should point out that I put in ignore as an attempt to fix the problem, but before and after I got the same result (and I think CreatedBy was set to null BTW). When I come back on Monday I shall look at Automapper.Collection.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu AutoMapper.Collection was the right answer

Comment: Good to know :)